# Core Data sum in relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a Category entity which has many expenses. I want to get the sum of all expenses for a category in a given month:

`- (NSNumber *)totalForMonth:(NSDate *)date
{
    ...`

```
NSPredicate *sumPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY %@ <= expenses.created_at) AND (ANY expenses.created_at <= %@)",
                             [date beginningOfMonth], [date endOfMonth]];

NSFetchRequest *req = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[req setPredicate:sumPredicate];
[req setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

return [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"expenses.@sum.amount"];
```

}

The problem with this code is that it throws an exception because apparently that's not the way to use @sum on a relationship.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to this, because I'm reading Apple's documentation and it never seems to do what it suggests it should.  I'm deriving an activity's duration by summing the duration of sub-activities, and it's giving me the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the @sum with the correct syntax. Most likely, you have just got another part of the keypath wrong e.g. "expenses" instead of "expense". Alternatively, you may be fetching the wrong entity.

If all you want to do is fetch this sum, do an attribute fetch and set your return type to dictionary. (See NSFetchRequest and Core Data Programming Guide) docs for details. That returns an array of dictionaries whose sole key is the attribute name and whose sole value is the value of selected attribute of one managed object. It's faster and uses fewer resources than fetching full objects.

Comment: He doesn't just want to get the sum of all expenses but also wants to get the sum over the particular predicate he's using (i.e. the dates between a given range). Thus a simple getter won't work for him.

Comment: He is not applying the collection operator to the fetch predicate but rather to the array of objects returned by the fetch. Therefore, he has the objects he wants to sum. As long as the keypath is correct `valueForKeyPath:` doesn't care where the objects came from.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a custom getter for it, and access it from there.

i.e.

**Category.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber* expensesSum;
```

**Category.m**

```
-(NSNumber*) expensesSum
{
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"expenses.@sum.amount"];
}
```

Also, you're currently returning `NSNumber *` when the request returns an array of children objects I believe.

Comment: I added that property and changed the last line of my method to: return [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"expensesSum"]; but now I get: the entity Category is not key value coding-compliant for the key "expenses.@sum.amount".

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?