# Sum on child object while displaying parent object - Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities in my core data application. Parent is Customer and child object is Order which has items purchased detail. Now what I want to display on my parent view controller is "Sum of Items" like this

Customer Name: Leo 
Order Total: £90

I am new to Core Data paradigm so please bear me. You create your fetch request based on one entity. My parent view controller's fetchResultController is fetching results for Customer. How can I at the same time can get customer order total?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145738/core-data-sum-in-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't think of entities being in a parent-child/tree structure unless your object graph actively enforces such a structure. In most cases it won't and any two entities are structural equals. That appears to be the case with your 'Customer' and 'Order' entities.

It's an important concept to grasp because unlike a conventional tree-structure, in a Core Data data graph, you can enter the graph at any instance of any entity and walk the relationships in any direction e.g. You don't have to always fetch a `Customer` object to start, you can if needed fetch a `Order` object just as easily.

In this particular case you are fetching `Customer` objects and you want to find all associated `Order` objects. Your data model should look something like this:

```
Customer{
  name:string
  orders<-->>Order.customer
}

Order{
  item:string
  cost:number
  customer<<-(required)->Customer.orders
}
```

Now, every time you create a new `Order`object you automatically link it the appropiate Customer object. When you fetch any particular `Customer` object all it's related `Order` objects are available in the `Customer.orders` relationship.

If you wanted to sum the cost of all a customer's orders, you could use a collection operator like so:

```
NSNumber *orderSum=[Customer.order valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.orders.cost"];
```

Relationships are very important to Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a go at home tonight.